# Using List Comprehension to rows of a list that are missing K entries (python)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Afternoon.  I'm currently trying to use list comprehension to return the rows of a list that do not have complete information.  My list is arranged from string values and is analogous to:

```
mylist = [['a', 'b', 'c',  'd'],
          ['b', '',  '',   'k'],
          ['',  '',  '',   'l'],
          ['1', '2', '',   '4'],
          ['6', '',  '10', '9'],
          ['6', '',  '',   '10']]
```

I would like to sort through this document and return the rows where any 1 value is missing , where any two values are missing, and so forth and so on for arbitrary number k, as so:

```
listwithoneelementmissing = [['6', '', '10', '9']]

listwithtwomissing = [['b', '', '', 'k'],
                      ['6', '', '', '10']]

listwiththreemissing = [['', '', '', 'l']]
```

I imagine there is a much more elegant way to do this than writing out every k choose n subset by hand and then using list comprehension.   Thanks!

Comment: by `missing` you mean *equal to empty string* or what?

Comment: I've updated your output to always be lists containing rows (lists), because you have *zero or more such matching rows*, not always exactly 1.

Comment: equal to empty string, yes.

sorry for missing the commas outside the row vectors.  today has not been very kind to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a function that returns the number of 'empty' values in a given list:

```
def count_empty(l):
    return sum(1 for v in l if not v)
```

You can then use this to partition your lists:

```
def partition_on_empty_count(rows):
    per_empty_count = {}
    for row in rows:
        per_empty_count.setdefault(count_empty(row), []).append(row)
    return per_empty_count
```

You now have a mapping from empty count to matching list:

```
>>> mylist = [['a', 'b', 'c',  'd'],
...           ['b', '',  '',   'k'],
...           ['',  '',  '',   'l'],
...           ['1', '2', '',   '4'],
...           ['6', '',  '10', '9'],
...           ['6', '',  '',   '10']]
>>>
>>> partition_on_empty_count(mylist)
{0: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']], 2: [['b', '', '', 'k'], ['6', '', '', '10']], 3: [['', '', '', 'l']], 1: [['1', '2', '', '4'], ['6', '', '10', '9']]}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
{0: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']],
 1: [['1', '2', '', '4'], ['6', '', '10', '9']],
 2: [['b', '', '', 'k'], ['6', '', '', '10']],
 3: [['', '', '', 'l']]}
```

Comment: this is great!  is it usually a better alternative to trying list comprehension?

Comment: @user7351362: **here** this is the better approach. List comprehensions have their place, and you can't generalise my solution to all situations where you can use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding.

What's wrong with: `results = [x for x in mylist if '' in x]` (return rows in which any element is '').  Alternatively one could use `results = [(i,r) for i,r in enumerate(mylist) if '' in r]` (return index and row for such cases).

You could even get fancy and return tuples of (index, count, row) for each of the rows missing any columns:

```
results = [(i,r.count(''), r) for i,r in enumerate(mylist) if '' in r]
```

The `in` operator in Python works on most containers (tuples, lists, sets, dictionaries, and for substrings in strings, bytes and bytarrays, etc).

For lists, tuples, strings, bytes and bytearrays you can also test for `.count(item) > 0`.

`enumerate()` is one of the most easily overlooked builtin functions in Python.  Obviously handy when you want to iterate over any collection and access the item indexes (row numbers) the same time.  The tuple unpacking form of the `for` loop (`for i,x in enumerate(stuff)`) makes the code in the loop cleaner, more concise, and easier to read).

Comment: I've used list comprehension in the past as you did in your first line, but I'm  having trouble extending it to searching for an arbitrary number of missing values across the columns (so not just particular column x and y, but all of them!)

could you explain your method when you get a chance?  thanks!

Comment: Added after the examples.